# Convert list of one number to int

Tags: regex, list, python-2.7, int

I have a regular expression that parses a line# string from a log. That line# is then subjected to another regular expression to just extract the line#.

For example:

Part of this regex:

```
m = re.match(r"^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s*\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}),?(\d{3}),?(?:\s+\[(?:[^\]]+)\])+(?<=])(\s+?[A-Z]+\s+?)+(\s?[a-zA-Z0-9\.])+\s?(\((?:\s?\w)+\))\s?(\s?.)+", line)
```

Will match this:

```
(line 206)
```

Then this regex:

```
re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', linestr)
```

Gives me

```
['206']
```

In order to further process my information I need to have the line number as an integer and am lost for a solution as to how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
line_int = int(re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', linestr)[0])
```

or if you have more than one element in the list:

```
lines_int = [int(i) for i in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', linestr)]
```

or even

```
lines_int = map(int, re.findall(r'(\b\d+\b)+', linestr))
```

I hope it helps -^.^-

Answer (score 1):

Use [int()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) to convert your list of one "string number" to an int:

```
 myl = ['206']
 int(myl[0])
 206
```

if you have a list of these, you can conver them all to ints using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[int(i) for i in myl]
```

resulting in a list of ints.

You can hook this into your code as best fits, e.g.,

`int(re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', linestr)[0])`

Answer (score 0):

```
int(re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', linestr)[0])
```

?